# Excel Vba Conditional Formatting copying

Tags: excel, vba

how can I copy a Row with a Rule from Conditional Formatting and put that rule on another row.

Here is what I got,

Rule................................Format...............................Appiles To

Formula =$D$187=$I$2 format of white background =$187:$187

Formula =$E$187>$D$32 Format of Gray background =$187:$187

Formula =$E$187=$D$32 Format of Gray background =$187:$187

Formula =$D$187>DATE(2010,1,1) Format of Yellow background =$187:$187

So what this does is If info in in cell D that row have back ground of Yellow And if Data in Cell E then the back ground is Gray.

My Problem is when I copy and past the format to another row it does not change the formula to 188 or 189 and so on I need this rule on Every Row and to only affect that row.

So what I had in mind was a Vba Code to Copy the row with the rule and just keep pasting it down a row lets say to like row 900 then go back and Loop and change all the Formula's

Comment: Change your CF formulas to omit the $ from the row number where the formatting is to be applied.  Eg  `$D187=$I$2` instead of `$D$187=$I$2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make your formula [relative](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/relative.aspx) for rows, like:

```
=$D187=$I$2
```

This assumes that all rows are looking at $I$2 for this condition, i.e., the $I$2 reference is absolute.

[image]

Comment: Hello I Don't want all the cells to change when its entered in.. I just want each row to so if row 196 has data in D only that row change then if 255 has data in it only that row change not all rows

Comment: Nerver mind that last comment thank you it works your that man

Comment: That worked for changeing it to yellow but how do i make the rest of my code like this

Comment: By making your other formulas row-relative also, by removing the "$" from in front of 187. And be sure to read the linked article, at least if you plan to keep using Excel :)

Comment: I removed the $ now its making them gray not working like it should =(

Comment: It changes to yellow but if the main one is gray the rest go gray